# yii2: how to add if for checked or unchecked checkbox in _form.php

Tags: yii, yii2

i want add if or else for checkbox in _formCreate.php

this is my checkbox:

```
   <div class="col-lg-6 height3">
         <p class="col-lg-8">سرگرمی</p>
<?= $form->field($model, 'c2')->input('checkbox', ['id' => '', 'value'=> '2', 'class' => 'col-lg-4 chb'])->label('') ?>

    </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 height3">
                <p class="col-lg-8">خدماتی</p>
<?= $form->field($model, 'c3')->input('checkbox', ['id' => '', 'value' => '3', 'class' => 'col-lg-4 chb'])->label('') ?>

            </div>
```

i have this variable in this form `$checkBox` with this data:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["project_type_id"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> array(1) { ["project_type_id"]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> array(1) { ["project_type_id"]=> string(1) "5" } }
```

how to add if for  `<?= $form->field...`   and check that with my array and checked  the checkbox!

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, then you can write logic for checkbox (model's attribute) in the beginning of the View. 
For example, if your model's name is 'Yii', then checkbox should be automatically checked, in code I would write it this way:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model SomeModel */

if($model->name == 'Yii') $model->c2 = true;

?>
```

Then in Form:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 height3">
  <p class="col-lg-8">سرگرمی</p>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'c2')->checkbox()->label('') ?>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 height3">
  <p class="col-lg-8">خدماتی</p>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'c3')->checkbox()->label('') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: if(1 ==1) 
    
{$model->c2 = true ; 
}
$model->c2 = true ;

Comment: However, check in the checkbox is not.

Comment: but
when i added 'checked' => true to my code
checkbox is check for just a moment and 
Automatic unchecked again !

Answer (score 0):

If model attribute set and model attribute value == checkbox value, then checkbox will checked

```
<?php 
if(in_array('2', ArrayHelper::map($checkBox, 'project_type_id', 'project_type_id'))) $model->c2 = '2';
if(in_array('3', ArrayHelper::map($checkBox, 'project_type_id', 'project_type_id'))) $model->c3 = '3';
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'c2')->input('checkbox', [
    'id' => '', 
    'value' => '2', 
    'class' => 'col-lg-4 chb'
])->label('') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'c3')->input('checkbox', [
    'id' => '', 
    'value' => '3', 
    'class' => 'col-lg-4 chb'
])->label('') ?>
```

Comment: However, check in the checkbox is false  .
how to find ('checked' => in_array(... )document for working with that !?

Comment: but
when i added 'checked' => true to my code
checkbox is check for just a moment and 
Automatic unchecked again !

Comment: Does not work.
And I think your code is correct and the problem is somewhere else. Because  is not checked this :

                   <?= $form->field($model, 'c2')->checkbox()->label('') ?>
                
<?php
$model->c2 = TRUE;
?>

Comment: Can you show all code, view, model and action in controller?